# Green Arrow 80th Anniversary 4-week challenge!

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

I recently learnt that there is a special [100-page, 80th anniversary edition](https://www.dccomics.com/comics/green-arrow-80th-anniversary-100-page-super-spectacular-2021/green-arrow-80th-anniversary-100) of the Green Arrow comic!

In celebration I'm going to put a 500 rep bounty on the **highest-scoring question** (to be given via an unrelated but still good answer or held until such an answer exists) and **highest-scoring answer**, as well as a **wild card question/answer of my choosing** on questions tagged with [green-arrow](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/green-arrow) and [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics) and NOT [arrow](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrow) (the TV-Series) NOR [arrowverse](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arrowverse) (that TV-Series' universe) that was posted from today, up until <strike>2 weeks</strike> 4 weeks from now (so ending 29th July 2021 midnight UTC). Full search for [questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgreen-arrow%5D+%5Bcomics%5D+-%5Barrowverse%5D+-%5Barrow%5D+created%3A2021-07-01..2021-07-29+is%3Aq), and for [answers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgreen-arrow%5D+%5Bcomics%5D+-%5Barrowverse%5D+-%5Barrow%5D+created%3A2021-07-01..2021-07-29+is%3Aa) for clarity (this does mean new answers on old questions are valid).

The question/answer does not need to be about the the special, but it will factor into my wild card choice!

Feel free to post suggestions to the wild card as answers!

<sub>Offer not affiliated with SE, SO, SFF, SA, SI, or SU or the mods thereof. Non-refundable, no monetary value on exchange. Do not tumbledry, not suitable for children under 13, GMO free and non-animal tested. Does not extend to any other comics, of either the book or stand-up variety.</sub>

Comment: Did you extend the deadline, or is this finished?

Comment: @Rand I intended to extend, but never made any updates. I'm a bit bummed we didn't get many questions.

Answer (score 5):

### **List of all questions posted as part of this topic challenge**

- [Has the Green Arrow gone on a different planet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/251028/58193) by [codeczar](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/96769/codeczar), 03/07/2021
- ...
- *add entries in the form `https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/<question-ID> by [username](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/<user-ID>), dd/07/2021.`*

---

The **highest-voted** of these is *[question URL]*, with a score of *TBD* at the end of the challenge.

The **most viewed** is *[question URL]*, with approximately *TBD* views during the challenge.